# Probability: Hazard Rate function

Tags: probability

I am trying to do the following question:

The lifetime X (in years) of an item has a rate function $λX(t) = t^2 + t^4 \,for\, t > 0$. What is the probability that

a) an item survives to age 1?

b) an item’s lifetime is between .5 and 1.5?

c) a 1/2 year old item will survive to age 1?

I'm not sure how to tackle this question. In my book it says that the hazard rate function is defined by $(t)=\frac{f(t)}{ \bar F(t)} \,$ where $\bar F = 1 - F$ but the rate function we are given isn't similar to this form? I suppose I'm suppose to use the rate function in the exponential distribution. The book gives a very small explanation about hazard rate functions, and only one example so I'm having a hard time understand it. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The key observation is to see that $f(t) = F'(t)$, hence $$\frac{f(t)}{1-F(t)} = \frac{d}{dt}\left[-\log(1-F(t))\right].$$  So by taking an integral, we can recover the cumulative distribution function in terms of the hazard function:  $$-\log (1 - F(t)) = \int_{u=0}^t \lambda(u) \, du,$$ for a distribution function with nonnegative support.  Consequently, $$S(t) = 1-F(t) = \exp \left( - \int_{u=0}^t \lambda(u) \, du \right);$$ that is to say, the **survival** function is the exponential (antilogarithm) of the negative integral of the hazard.  Sometimes the integral itself is called the **cumulative hazard** function, e.g., $$\Lambda(t) = \int_{u=0}^t \lambda(u) \, du,$$ in an analogous sense that a cumulative distribution function is an integral of the density.

So, if we are given $$\lambda(t) = \frac{f(t)}{S(t)} = t^2 + t^4, \quad t > 0,$$ then what is $\Lambda(t)$?  What is $1-F(t)$?  And finally, how do we use $F(t)$ to compute the desired probabilities $$\Pr[0.5 \le X \le 1.5], \quad \Pr[X > 1 \mid X > 1/2],$$ if $X$ represents the lifetime random variable?

Comment: I am sort of confused about to survival function. Is it not suppose to produce the same result as the density function? Because for question a), I got S(1) = 0.587 and f(1) = 0.413